# TO check response of particular id should be diff through jmeter

Tags: jmeter

MY response for api is:-

```
"data":{"shortId":"lu131559"}}
```

Now i wants to check short id is different for every virtual user.
mns if second hit gone response data is

```
lu131560
```

So i want to validate that after 1000 request from virtual user every time i am getting diff id.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the "current" value of the `shortId` and expect it to be incremented by `1` each time you call your API you can go for [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) and use [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) and [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) functions combination in the pattern like:

```
lu${__intSum(131559,${__counter(,)},)}
```

[image]

Each time the Assertion will be called it will expect the value to be incremented by one, i.e.

- `lu131560` - for 1st user or iteration
- `lu131561` - for 2nd user or iteration
- `lu131562` - for 3rd user or iteration
- etc.

More information: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction/)

Comment: HI Dmitri,
Actually i initially i dont know the shortid number. it may vary.any 6 digit number may come. all i need to check wether i am getting diff response in 1000 virtual user hit. I just paste the first response. may be next it may come lu427665.or any 6 digit. but i need to sure they are distinct for every hit